# What to do to be able to search a word from label in VB.net directly from code?

Tags: vb.net, search, text, combobox, label

[image]

These codes are working.
After trying these codes with the help of sir ClearlyClueless, I still can't figure out how can I change the combobox when i click the button 3.
I tries the code in button 3 and it doesn't work.

the combobox has items 0,1,2,3

I I click the button 3, it will show msgbox"your message" since the word on the code is matching the word in the label. but it doesn't work.
Because if it worked, then I can now change the msgbox a combobox1.selectedindex = 0

Comment: Show the code, in text not in an image, of where you're changing the combobox value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution.

This codes helped me.

```
If Label1.Text.ToUpper.Contains("wanna be A ".ToUpper) Then
        MsgBox("The code is working")
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2
    End If
```